# std::execution::par does not spawn threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, c++20

I am trying to parallelize the processing of `problems` contained in a `vector`. To do so I would like to first try to avoid `std::thread`, given that the std provides parallel execution methods which should cover my use case. My understanding of how to apply it is this:

```cpp
std::vector<SolutionT> solution_vector;
std::mutex mut;
std::for_each(std::execution::par, problems.begin(), problems.end(), [&](const auto& problem) {
   auto solution = do_heavy_work(problem)
   std::lock_guard guard(mut);
   solution_vector.emplace_back(solution);
}
```

In CMake I also add the threads lib to the executable (although unsure if necessary?):

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(
        executable 
        PRIVATE 
        Threads::Threads
)
```

The solving time for a problem ranges from mere milliseconds to tens of seconds and since I have a thousand problems in my vector and most are of the larger kind, so I am expecting parallelism to speed up this processing time a fair bit.

Yet, when I run the code I do not observe any threads being spawned. I check the processes with `htop` and observe only a single core being pushed to 100% while the rest are idle.

Am I wrong in expecting threads to be spawned in combination with std::execution::par? Am I missing a step to get this right?

This was tested on an 18-core Intel x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04 platform with GCC 11.4 and c++20.

Edit:
Here is a godbolt example that reflects my usage: https://godbolt.org/z/EEMEWr3Wa

Comment: Would something change in case you embrace additionally with `{` and `}' two lines with definition of the `guard` and calling `emplace_back` to make sure that `guard`'s scope is limited? Otherwise, it would help if you show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example at [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: @DamirTenishev I do in fact have my lock guard in its own scope so that RAII does the unlocking. I opted to remove it in the example to simplify the logic since it would not have had an effect there. Anyway, I added a godbolt example that reflects what I am seeing locally too.

Comment: On my 16-core PC with MSVC2022 it shows many threads. They key here is that the workload could be small or the overhead of creating new threads outweighs the benefits of parallel execution. In such cases, the standard library implementation may choose to execute the tasks sequentially instead of creating new threads. This decision is typically based on heuristics and may vary across different implementations. You may look in the `stdlib` sources how these decisions could be made. No better clues for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [execution_policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t)

> If the implementation cannot parallelize or vectorize (e.g. due to lack of resources), all standard execution policies can fall back to sequential execution.

See the lines of the generated [code](https://godbolt.org/z/EEMEWr3Wa) from your link (lines 228 of the generated code and further).

```
movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x30],xmm0
 movdqa xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # 230 <heavy_work[abi:cxx11](std::shared_ptr<int> const&)+0x1c0>
    R_X86_64_PC32 .LC5-0x4
```

Instead of spawning threads it does vectorization.

It could be another good question why vectorization applied with `std::execution::par`.

The recommended reading here might include [this paper](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2018/072651a8229a63376d5720c9a500ae45_MIT6_172F18hw3.pdf).